# How to extract data of last week from Firebird database?

Tags: sql, firebird

I am having trouble of getting the query working, the database is a Firebird database, and the tool I use for querying the data is DBeaver. - work requirement, no other choice.
The goal is run the query and only pull the data of last week, here is one of the queries I have tried:

```
select *
from table 1
where 1.payment_rundate > dateadd(DAY, -7,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

I find that `dateadd` syntax is not recognized in DBeaver.

Comment: What is the exact error your get and what is your Firebird version, because [`DATEADD`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-dateadd) is the correct function

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't [`DATEADD`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-dateadd), the problem is that the Firebird syntax doesn't allow `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, it only allows [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-contextvars-current-timestamp.html) (no parentheses) or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(precision)` where *precision* is 0 - 3.

In other words, use the condition:

```sql
payment_rundate > dateadd(DAY, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Part of the problem is that DBeaver's autocompletion generates `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` and positions the cursor inside the parentheses, expecting you to enter the desired precision. If you don't want to specify precision, it is up to you to delete those parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with `interval`

```
select *
from table 1
where 1.payment_rundate between (current_date - INTERVAL 7 DAY) and current_date
```

Comment: Firebird doesn't have interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think just the below will do the trick :

```
select *
  from table 1
 where 1.payment_rundate >= current_date - 6
```

if payment_rundate is a timestamp then you can go with that :

```
select *
  from table 1
 where cast(1.payment_rundate as date) >= current_date - 6
```